# Remove fade in Polymer Core-Scaffold

Tags: html, css, polymer

I've been working with MeteorJS and Polymer integration. I've done quite some code but I'm very poor at Design especially with CSS. Any idea how I can remove the fade in the area boxed in Red? I can change the background color, but I don't know how to remove the fading.

[image]

I'm using the following code for the Meteor Template:

```
<template name="default_template">
<head>
  <title>agus</title>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-decorator.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-autogrow-textarea.html">

  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html">
</head>

<body>
  <core-scaffold>
    <core-header-panel navigation flex>
      <core-toolbar id="navheader">
        <span>Menu</span>
      </core-toolbar>
      <core-menu>
        <core-item label="Profile" id="mnuItemProfile"></core-item>
        <core-item label="Dashboard" id="mnuItemDashboard"></core-item>
      </core-menu>
    </core-header-panel>

    <span tool>Agus System</span>

    <div class="content">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  </core-scaffold>
</body>
</template>
```

My css only changes colors. Any recommendations (in css) on removing the fade?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "seamed" mode for `core-header-panel` as in the [`core-header-panel` demo](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/demo.html):

```
<core-header-panel mode="seamed"></core-header-panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set box-shadow to none, on the element you are changing the background color, so

```
box-shadow: none;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi @robjez somehow I have not been able to successfully remove the fade using your suggestion. [Unable to make it work.](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/F1p_aA5DaKmbCcrAr_AxWj5dCyO6usMlQmnbZnddPu-nHzDnPU0HKNzx_78pAsxdnAlKlGHVW9s=w1256-h789)

Comment: Could be great if I could have a look into browsers's web developer tools, but I guess you play with it locally? What is the css on span element inside of #navheader? You can try to disable all box-shadow related rules in web developer, as it really looks like you need to search for this property to me. Also can you switch to "computed" tab in css panel of web developer, and tick "Show inherited properties" checkbox, and scroll down to see what's the box-shadow computed value on #navheader ?